# node - On kill event

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

Is there a way to run a function when the node.js process is killed?

This is what I'm aiming for (in C):

```
signal(SIGSEGV, sig_handler);

void sig_handler(int sig) {
    if (sig == SIGSEGV) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

So, is it possible to do this in node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep,

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  console.log('Got SIGINT.  Press Control-D to exit.');
});
```

Taken from the documentation:

http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events